# Adding images to groups in facebook graph api not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble getting the graph API to post images into a group.
I have no trouble posting into a group feed, but as soon as I try and upload an image into the group I get the following not so helpful error message:

> An unknown error has occurred.

I am using the php facebook toolkit.

A summary of my code can be seen below:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$file = "image.jpg";
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$args = array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'message' => 'Photo Caption',
    'image' => '@' . realpath($file),
);

$result = $facebook->api('/<group_id>/photos', 'post', $args);
```

If I replace the group_id with "me" then it works and the photo is uploaded to the user's photos.

I have all the required privileges enabled for the app.

Can anybody help me with this as it's driving me nuts?

Comment: There is nothing in the docs for the group object https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/ that suggest this would be possible.

Comment: so then how would I post an image to a group?  I can post an image thumbnail as part of a feed but I need to post full width images in exactly the same way as the above code would to my own feed.

Comment: _“so then how would I post an image to a group?”_ – if the API currently not offers that functionality (which it looks like) – then of course, _you don’t_.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have now fixed this issue (it is possible in the way I suggested) it was a feature that was temporarily suspended by Facebook groups team.  It is now working in UK as of Thursday 8th Nov 2013.